# Does the series of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{n-1}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the following sum converge?
$$
  \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{n-1}
$$
Have tried ratio test and root test, inconclusive. alternating series test not useful.

Comment: How about the $n$th term test for divergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{n+1}{n-1}$ converge, then there exist a $N$ such that $\forall n \geq N$

$$L-\frac{1}{3} < \sum_{n=2}^{2N}(-1)^n \frac{n+1}{n-1} < L+\frac{1}{3}$$

But then

$$L-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2N+2}{2N} < \sum_{n=2}^{2N+1}(-1)^n \frac{n+1}{n-1} < L+\frac{1}{3} - \frac{2N+2}{2N}$$

But $\frac{2N+2}{2N}> \frac{2}{3}$, then

$$L-1 < \sum_{n=2}^{2N+1}(-1)^n \frac{n+1}{n-1} < L-\frac{1}{3} $$

contradiction

This is the idea of the proof of why the general term must converge to 0

Comment: Sometime it's good to remember **why** the general term of a serie must converge to 0 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

What is
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n-1}? $$

Comment: I think a more accurate hint would be "What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n\frac{n+1}{n-1}$?" That directly invokes the fact that in a convergent series, the summand must tend to $0$.

Comment: @GregMartin I considered that, but I chose this since this limit actually exists. Also, you gave away the hint! ;-)

Comment: I know "limit((n+1)/(n-1),x = infinity) = 1"

Comment: @user221318 Correct. Do you know what is required for an infinite series? Particularly, do you know what is required of the summand for the series to converge?

Comment: that they decrease as n-> infinity

Comment: @user221318 Exactly, specifically they should decrease all down to...?

Comment: As I wrote in my question I have tried alternating series test etc. Problem is that I run out of convergence tests. And therefore need to star testing for divergence. And that seem much harder. How to prove that the sum diverges???

Comment: @user221318 It is very simple in this case, considering what we have discussed in this chat.

Comment: to concider the difference between two consecutive partial sums? S(n)-S(n+1) ??

Comment: @user221318 I can't really leave any more hints without giving it away, so I guess I'll just do that: [term test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test)

Answer (score 0):

Let
$s(m)
=\sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{n-1}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
s(2m+1)
&=\sum_{n=2}^{2m+1} \frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} (\frac{(-1)^{2n}(2n+1)}{2n-1}+\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}(2n+1+1)}{2n+1-1})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} (\frac{(2n+1)}{2n-1}-\frac{(2n+2)}{2n})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} (\frac{2n-1+2}{2n-1}-\frac{n+1}{n})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} (1+\frac{2}{2n-1}-(1+\frac{1}{n}))\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} (\frac{2}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{n})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{2n-(2n-1)}{n(2n-1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac1{n(2n-1)}\\
&\to c
\qquad\text{for some real }c\text{ since the sum converges}\\
s(2m+2)
&=s(2m+1)+ \frac{(-1)^{2m+2}(2m+2+1)}{2m+2-1}\\
&=s(2m+1)+ \frac{(2m+3)}{2m+1}\\
&=s(2m+1)+ 1+\frac{2}{2m+1}\\
&\to c+1\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore the even terms and odd sums
approach different limits,
so the series itself
does not have a limit.

Note:
this also works for
$\sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac{(-1)^n(n+a)}{n+b}
$
with $a \ne b$.